# How to group distinct rows and add count of a category into new columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
Game_ID Games     Match_Date    Total_Games_Each_Day     F_or_C
1       Football  2019-07-10    5                        2
2       Cricket   2019-07-10    5                        3
3       Cricket   2019-07-10    5                        3
4       Football  2019-07-10    5                        2
5       Cricket   2019-07-10    5                        3
6       Football  2019-07-11    6                        4
7       Cricket   2019-07-11    6                        2
8       Cricket   2019-07-11    6                        2
9       Football  2019-07-11    6                        4
10      Football  2019-07-11    6                        4
11      Football  2019-07-11    6                        4
12      Football  2019-07-16    6                        6
13      Football  2019-07-16    6                        6
14      Football  2019-07-16    6                        6
```

1.remove the duplicates ['Match_Date', 'Games' ]
i.e Number of Football(F)  played on 2019-07-10 + Cricket played on 2019-07-10(C) = 5(F_or_C) ,

Number of Football(F)  played on 2019-07-11 + Cricket played on 2019-07-11(C) = 6(F_or_C) and so on

2.Add a column F and C  such as the final data looks like this:

```
Game_ID Games     Match_Date    Total_Games_Each_Day     F_or_C  F     C
1       Football  2019-07-10    5                        2       2     Null
2       Cricket   2019-07-10    5                        3       Null  3
3       Football  2019-07-11    6                        4       4     Null
4       Cricket   2019-07-11    6                        2       Null  2
5       Football  2019-07-16    6                        6       6     Null
```

Null in F column represents no Football played on that day and same is for C column.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: game.groupby([ 'Match_Date', 'Games'])['Game ID'].count() does not work. and using drop_duplicates also gives problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need `drop_duplicates` with `crosstab`

```
from io import StringIO
# read your dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(your_data),sep='\s+',parse_dates=['Match_Date'])
#note the datetime column.
s = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Match_Date','Games'])


new_df = s.join(pd.crosstab(s.index, s.Games.str[0], s["F_or_C"], aggfunc="first"))

    Game_ID     Games Match_Date  Total_Games_Each_Day  F_or_C    C    F
0         1  Football 2019-07-10                     5       2  NaN  2.0
1         2   Cricket 2019-07-10                     5       3  3.0  NaN
5         6  Football 2019-07-11                     6       4  NaN  4.0
6         7   Cricket 2019-07-11                     6       2  2.0  NaN
11       12  Football 2019-07-16                     6       6  NaN  6.0
```